# Indexing empty array, Numba vs. Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I was experimenting with the behavior of `Numba` vs `Numpy` for array indexing, and I came across something which I do not quite understand; so I hoped someone can point me in the right direction for what is probably a very simple question. Below are two functions, both of which create an empty array using the np.arange command. I then "append" (experimenting with a variety of methods to see how both `Numba` and `Numpy` perform/break) to the array using an index of 0, `example[0] = 1`.

The `Numba` function with `jit` runs without error, but the `Numpy` example gives the error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

The `Numpy` error makes sense, but I am unsure as to why `Numba` with `jit` enabled allows the operation without error.

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit()
def funcnumba():
    '''
    Add item to position 0 using Numba
    '''
    example = np.arange(0)
    example[0] = 1
    return example

def funcnumpy():
    '''
    Add item to position 0 using Numpy. This produces an error which makes sense
    '''
    example = np.arange(0)
    example[0] = 1
    return example

print(funcnumba())

print(funcnumpy())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Numba documentation on arrays](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/arrays.html):

> Currently there are no bounds checking for array indexing and slicing (...)

That means that you will be writing out of the bounds of the array in this case. Since it is just one element you may be lucky and get away with it, but you can also crash your program or, even worse, silently overwrite some other value. See [issue #730](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/730) for a discussion about it.

Comment: I'm confused, why does it throw the error when there are no bounds checks? Isn't this more to do with numpy treating single item arrays as scalars?

Comment: In fact, `np.arange(0)` seems to me to be inviting wonky behaviour tbh. Does it have a purpose?

Comment: @roganjosh It's the NumPy function the one that raises the error, not the Numba one (which makes sense, because NumPy does implement bounds checking). `np.arange(0)` is an empty array, not a single-item one. Wrt its utility, I'd say it's a matter of consistence. I have probably used it when I needed something to work whether the result should be empty or not.